# Streamlit app not loading when running using Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

I have a basic streamlit code that I want to run using a dockerfile:

app.py

```
# app.py
import streamlit as st

def main():
    st.title("Basic Streamlit App")
    
    # Add some text
    st.write("This is a simple Streamlit app.")

    # Add a slider widget
    number = st.slider("Select a number", 1, 100, 50)

    # Display the selected number
    st.write("You selected:", number)

    # Add a button
    if st.button("Click me"):
        st.write("Button clicked!")

    # Add a checkbox
    checkbox_state = st.checkbox("Check me")
    st.write("Checkbox state:", checkbox_state)

    # Add a selectbox
    options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    selected_option = st.selectbox("Select an option", options)
    st.write("You selected:", selected_option)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "–server.port=8501", "–server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

requirements.txt

```
streamlit
```

I run the following commands:

`docker build -t streamlit-docker:0.0.1.RELEASE .`

`docker run -p 8501:8501 streamlit-docker:0.0.1.RELEASE`

```
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.


  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://172.17.0.4:8501
```

When I open the URL, the page does not load and returns: This site can’t be reached

I just started with Docker and want to understand where I am going wrong. I tried looking at https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/deploy/docker as well.

EDIT: It works on Mozilla Firefox(122.0.1), but for some reason it does not work when I open the link using Chrome (Version 121.0.6167.184 (Official Build) (arm64))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `server.address` argument is not passed to the streamlit app properly. If you look at the IP address of your app, its deployed to `172.17.0.4` and not `0.0.0.0`.

In the `CMD` line of your Dockerfile, it looks like you are missing a hyphen?
This is from the docs:
`ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "streamlit_app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]`

The docs use double hyphens, but your Dockerfile only has one hyphen.

Once the app is deployed to 0.0.0.0, you should be able to access the app at http://0.0.0.0:8501 or http://localhost:8501